# Kubernetes Google Container Engine HTTPS Load Balancer Error

Tags: https, load-balancing, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Does anyone know if Google’s HTTPS loadbalancer is working?
I was working on setting up a NGINX ingress service but I noticed the Google Loadbalancer was automatically being setup by Kubernetes. I was getting two external IPs instead of one. So instead of setting up the NGINX load balancer I decided to use the Google service. I deleted my container cluster, created a brand new one. I started my HTTP pod and HTTP service on port 80. I then created my ingress service and L7 controller pod. Now I'm getting the following error when I review the load balancer logs:

> Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default",
>   Name:"echomap", UID:"9943e74c-76de-11e6-8c50-42010af0009b",
>   APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"7935", FieldPath:""}): type:
>   'Warning' reason: 'GCE' googleapi: Error 400: Validation failed for
>   instance
>   'projects/mundolytics/zones/us-east1-c/instances/gke-airportal-default-pool-7753c577-129e':
>   instance may belong to at most one load-balanced instance group.,
>   instanceInMultipleLoadBalancedIgs

Comment: I went ahead and tried the example located at: [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/gce) and I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have one or more hanging backend services. Run `gcloud compute backend-services list` to find them and then `gcloud compute backend-services delete [SERVICE-NAME]` for each service to remove it.

```
$ gcloud compute backend-services list
NAME                            BACKENDS                                                             PROTOCOL
my-hanging-service              us-central1-a/instanceGroups/gke-XXXXXXX-default-pool-XXXXXXX-grp  HTTP

$ gcloud compute backend-services delete my-hanging-service
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. When i want to delete the backend service it gives me this error `ERROR: (gcloud.compute.backend-services.delete) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The backend_service resource 'projects/myprojectname/global/backendServices/backend-service' is already being used by 'projects/myprojectname/global/urlMaps/
darbar-load-balancer'`